Understanding exchange in spark ui
I am learning about Spark and came across the following thing. I create a simple dataframe using range.
ids = spark.range(1,9,1,4)

Then I repartition this dataframe using some logic and build a new dataframe as follows.
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
q = ids.repartition(col("id") % 2)

Now, if I run debugString on the new df.
q.rdd.toDebugString()

Output -
(1) MapPartitionsRDD[16] at javaToPython at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[15] at javaToPython at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0 []
 |  SQLExecutionRDD[14] at javaToPython at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0 []
 |  ShuffledRowRDD[13] at  at LexicalThreadLocal.scala:63 []
 +-(4) MapPartitionsRDD[12] at  at LexicalThreadLocal.scala:63 []    <-- This RDD
    |  MapPartitionsRDD[11] at  at LexicalThreadLocal.scala:63 []
    |  MapPartitionsRDD[10] at  at LexicalThreadLocal.scala:63 []
    |  ParallelCollectionRDD[9] at  at LexicalThreadLocal.scala:63 []

I'm interested in the MapPartitionsRDD[12] (the one just below ShuffledRowRDD). The RDD can be seen in the Spark UI as well. I've marked it in the below image that is generated by running q.show(). Here the number of partitions are 200 (set by default value of spark.sql.shuffle.partitions).

(The numbers in name of MapPartitionsRDD in photo is different from the output since both are formed by separate commands.)
After this exchange task, the number of partitions are reduced to 1 for the ShuffledRowRDD. This can be verified in the UI as well.

If MapPartitionsRDD has 4 partitions and ShuffledRowRDD has 1 partition, where did the 200 partitions go?
This is my reasoning after gathering all the information  I could.

If MapPartitionsRDD had 200 partitions then it would have been kept in a separate stage in the UI since each stage ends at wide transformations. Also, it's name should have been different and not MapRDD.
The ShuffledRowRDD has 1 partition because of coalescing done by adaptive query execution of Spark.
So, partitioning and shuffling happened in-between the two stages. And the number of partitions shown in spark ui, the ones in black boxes are not related to the partitions in RDD.

Are the above reasons correct? If so, then what is the use of Exchange in Spark UI? Also, what does the number of partitions in Spark UI (SQL section) represent?

Before progressing, it is a good idea to specify the version of spark for the benefit of the audience.
You start with basically two lines
>>> ids = spark.range(1,9,1,4)
>>> q = ids.repartition(col("id") % 2)

To investigate what is going on, try the following to provide explanation
>>> q.explain(True)
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'RepartitionByExpression [('id % 2)]
    +- Range (1, 9, step=1, splits=Some(4))

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
id: bigint
RepartitionByExpression [(id#14L % cast(2 as bigint))]
+- Range (1, 9, step=1, splits=Some(4))

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
RepartitionByExpression [(id#14L % 2)]
+- Range (1, 9, step=1, splits=Some(4))

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Exchange hashpartitioning((id#14L % 2), 200), REPARTITION_BY_COL, 
[plan_id=41]
   +- Range (1, 9, step=1, splits=4)

>>> ids = spark.range(1,9,1,4)
>>> q = ids.repartition(col("id") % 2)
>>> q.explain(True)
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'RepartitionByExpression [('id % 2)]
+- Range (1, 9, step=1, splits=Some(4))

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
id: bigint
RepartitionByExpression [(id#18L % cast(2 as bigint))]
+- Range (1, 9, step=1, splits=Some(4))

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
RepartitionByExpression [(id#18L % 2)]
+- Range (1, 9, step=1, splits=Some(4))

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Exchange hashpartitioning((id#18L % 2), 200), REPARTITION_BY_COL, 
[plan_id=49]
   +- Range (1, 9, step=1, splits=4)

With q = ids.repartition(col("id") % 2): you are repartitioning the DF ids based on a user-defined logic. With repartition() you are redistributing the data across partitions based on the (col("id") % 2). However, the key point is that while the code specifies repartitioning based on the modulo operation, the actual execution plan might involve a shuffle operation due to Spark's internal optimization strategies. So Spark may not be able to guarantee an even distribution of data across two partitions using just the modulo operation. It might need to shuffle the data to align with the desired partitioning scheme.
While you repartition based on id % 2, Spark might shuffle data due to internal optimizations. The modulo operation might not ensure a perfect split across two partitions with the existing partition layout (4 partitions from range). The line of output that shows the shuffle operation in the q.explain(True) is
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Exchange hashpartitioning((id#18L % 2), 200), REPARTITION_BY_COL, 

Exchange is the keyword showing that a shuffle operation is happening. Meaning that Spark needs to exchange data between executors to achieve the optimum partitioning
HTH
Mich Talebzadeh,
Technologist | Architect | Data Engineer  | Generative AI | FinCrime

Hey, thanks for the answer. I think you misunderstood the question. I don't want to know why the number of partitions are not equal to 2. I wanted to know if shuffle happened and as shown in the photo, the number of partitions were 200. Which RDD had 200 partitions? If shuffling happens in Exchange, why did the debugString still show only 4 partitions? Shouldn't the debugstring show 200 for the MapPartitionRDD just before ShuffleRowRDD (because that MapRDD is the one used for exchange)?

The debugString may not necessarily show 200 partitions for the RDD just before the shuffle (Exchange).  DebugString shows the lineage of the RDD, which represents the chain of transformations applied to the data. The shuffle operation itself might be a separate stage in the execution plan.

Shuffle operation is always carried out in a separate stage. By default the number of shuffle partitions is 200 @Dhruv but there could be scenarios where it is not necessary to include all the 200 partitions. It depends on your data. So if your data can fit in 2/4 partitions you will see that value only. It depends on the cardinality of the data you are trying to repartition on.

@RushHour I get that the number of partitions is dependent on data. I just wanted to know why Spark UI was showing 200 partitions. I guessed 200 partitions were used only for shuffle and later coalesced to form a shuffledRDD with 4 partitions. I just wanted to confirm that with some proof, like an excerpt from the source code.

I think you got the source code over the email right?
